# Xubuntu - Set Keyboard Shortcuts with Script

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, shortcut-keys

Does anybody know how I can write a script to define my keyboard shortcuts in Xubuntu 18.04?

I am constantly setting up new computers with the distro, and I would like to add this to my "installation script" that sets up my computer how I like it. I used to do it using the following on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
#!/bin/bash

BEGINNING="gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings"

KEY_PATH="/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings"

gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings \
"['$KEY_PATH/custom0/', '$KEY_PATH/custom1/', '$KEY_PATH/custom2/', '$KEY_PATH/custom3/', '$KEY_PATH/custom4/', '$KEY_PATH/custom5/']"

# Take a screenshot of the entire display
$BEGINNING/custom0/ name "Take Full Screenshot"
$BEGINNING/custom0/ command "shutter --full"
$BEGINNING/custom0/ binding "Print"

# ...
```

... but that doesn't work in Xubuntu as I get the following message:

```
No such schema “org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding”
```

Comment: Should be possible with `xfconf-query`

Comment: XFCE isn't GNOME.  I haven't done what you want, nor am I using 18.04 so cannot look, but I'd have looked for changes in `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml`  (*this is on my 20.04 which is fully GTK3 unlike your 18.04; but I doubt it makes a difference, but*...)